# How to add another Paper variable to JointJs HTML view?

Tags: javascript, html, jointjs

I am going thorough the jointjs tutorial, in particular HelloWorld (http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial#hello-world).  The basic example works fine except for the fact that the space in text: 'my box', results in the strange character.  However, adding another small paper as suggested in the tutorial does not work, I do not get 2 working papers as indicated in the tutorial.  The suggested addition is

```
var paperSmall = new joint.dia.Paper({
el: $('#myholder-small'),
width: 600,
height: 100,
model: graph,
gridSize: 1
});
paperSmall.scale(.5);
paperSmall.$el.css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

How to combine the addition with the main code? The main code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="joint.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<script src="joint.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#myholder'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});

var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
});

var rect2 = rect.clone();
rect2.translate(300);

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect.id },
    target: { id: rect2.id }
});

graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the tutorial does not specify that the second Paper should be associated with another div in HTML:

```
<div id="myholder-small"></div>
```